# How to use byte array as key in RDD?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, garbage-collection

I want to use Array[Byte] as Key from RDD. For example:

```
val rdd1:RDD[((Array[Byte]), (String, Int)] = from src rdd
val rdd2:RDD[((Array[Byte]), (String, Int)] = from dest rdd

val resultRdd = rdd1.join(rdd2)
```

I want to perform join operation on rdd1 and rdd2 using Array[Byte] as Key
but always getting resultRdd.count() = 0.

So I tried to serialize the Array[Byte] and It is working fine as I want to see, only for small Dataset.

```
val serRdd1= rdd1.map { case (k,v) =>  (new SerByteArr(k), v) }
val serRdd2= rdd2.map { case (k,v) =>  (new SerByteArr(k), v) }

class SerByteArr(val bytes: Array[Byte]) extends Serializable {
   override val hashCode = bytes.deep.hashCode
   override def equals(obj:Any) = obj.isInstanceOf[SerByteArr] && obj.asInstanceOf[SerByteArr].bytes.deep == this.bytes.deep
 }
```

For Large dataset, getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded,
Problem is occuring in creating the object(new SerByteArr(k)).

How to avoid the GC limit exceed error. Does anyone help me?

Comment: how large are your arrays? Would it make sense to replace them with a hash?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a built-in scala wrapper for arrays, `WrappedArray[Byte]`. An array can be converted to a WrappedArray by using toSeq method. WrappedArray has properly implemented `equals` and `hashCode`, so two different arrays with the same elements are considered as equal.

```
scala> val a = Array(1,2,3,4,5)
a: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> val b = Array(1,2,3,4,5)
b: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> a == b
res0: Boolean = false

scala> a.toSeq
res1: Seq[Int] = WrappedArray(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> a.toSeq == b.toSeq
res2: Boolean = true
```